# How to go through each elementin a list and update them?

Tags: python

For example, I have the list:

```
list1[]= [0.75, 0.29, 0.3]
```

And i want to create a function that goes through each element and multiplies them by 2 and updates the list (or saves it as a new list)

Comment: Read up on "List comprehensions"

Comment: `list1 = [i * 2 for i in list1]`

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this code snippet**

```
def update(lst):
    nl=[]
    for i in lst:
        nl.append(i*2)
    return nl
```

Comment: refer the comment of  https://stackoverflow.com/users/3799759/samwise list1 = [i * 2 for i in list1]

Answer (score 0):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list1 = [0.75, 0.29, 0.3]
list1 = [i * 2 for i in list1]
```